# After purchasing a product in WooCommerce add the related order ID as user metadata

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

After buying a product add this product order ID in this user meta. I can check the product bought status using this `wc_customer_bought_product()`. Now I need to get this product order id using UserID and product ID. How can I achieve this? My ultimate goal is after getting order id I will remove order by this function `wp_delete_post()`

```
$bronze = wc_customer_bought_product($current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, 246014);

function get_customerorderid(){
    global $post;
    $order_id = $post->ID;

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    // Get the user ID from WC_Order methods
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id(); // or $order->get_customer_id();

    return $user_id;
}
get_customerorderid();
wp_delete_post(246014,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that making a custom sql query embedded in a function, using [`WPDB`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) Class, this way:

```
function get_completed_orders_for_user_from_product_id( $product_id, $user_id = 0 ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $order_status = 'wc-completed';

    // If optional $user_id argument is not set, we use the current user ID
    $customer_id = $user_id === 0 ? get_current_user_id() : $user_id;

    // Return customer orders IDs containing the defined product ID
    return $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT DISTINCT woi.order_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta pm
            ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items woi
            ON p.ID = woi.order_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta woim
            ON woi.order_item_id = woi.order_item_id
        WHERE p.post_status = '%s'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND pm.meta_value = '%d'
        AND woim.meta_key IN ( '_product_id', '_variation_id' )
        AND woim.meta_value LIKE '%d'
        ORDER BY woi.order_item_id DESC
    ", $order_status, $customer_id, $product_id ) );
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme)*. Tested and works.

---

**USAGE** with `wp_delete_post()` to remove related orders containing a specific product *(id: **`246014`**)*:

```
// Get all orders containing 246014 product ID for the current user 
$orders_ids = get_completed_orders_for_user_from_product_id( 246014 );

// Checking that, the orders IDs array is not empty
if( count($orders_ids) > 0 ) {

    // Loop through orders IDs
    foreach ( $orders_ids as $order_id ) {
        // Delete order post data 
        wp_delete_post( $order_id, true );
    }

    // Add the order(s) ID(s) in user meta (example)
    update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'item_246014', implode( ',', $orders_ids ) );
}
```

---

Related threads:

- [Get all Orders IDs from a product ID in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664819/get-all-orders-ids-from-a-product-id-in-woocommerce/43669138#43669138)
- [Changing WooCommerce processing orders status based on product stock quantity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57938647/changing-woocommerce-processing-orders-status-based-on-product-stock-quantity/57940046#57940046)

Comment: `get_completed_orders_from_customer_from_product_id()` and `get_completed_orders_for_user_from_product_id()` is not same.

Comment: @Kane Sorry, I have updated my code (a renaming mistake)… The function code works and the usage code should work too.